# Проблема с увеличением размера массива символов с помощью realloc (СИ)

Tags: c, visual-studio, realloc

Пытаюсь разобраться как работает realloc с массивами символов. Столкнулся с ошибкой HEAP CORRUTPION.

Создаю динамический одномерный массив name и в цикле наполняю его словами, введенные пользователем. При этом совершаю (безуспешную) попытку расширить массив на размер введенного слова + старый размер.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int sym = 0;
    char* name = NULL;

    int index;
    for (index = 0; index < 2; index++)
    {
        char temp[15] = "";
        printf("ENTER: ");
        fgets(temp, 15, stdin);
        name = realloc(name, (strlen(temp) + sym) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(&name[sym], temp);
        sym += strlen(temp);
    }

    free(name);
}
```

P.s Относительно похожий код, но с массивом чисел работает абсолютно без ошибок.

Comment: Не хватает места под нулевой символ в конце строки. `(strlen(temp) + sym)` -> `(strlen(temp) + 1 + sym)`.

Comment: `name = realloc(name, ` - это антипаттерн. Всегда надо присваивать результат новой переменной, проверять на NULL и затем копировать в старую. Иначе, при сбое, вы потеряете старую память и не получите новую.

Comment: да, это известный антипаттерн, но тут нужно смотреть на каждую ситуацию. В обычной ученической задаче вполне нормально без проверки. В коде нормально промышленного кода - да, проверка нужна., в коде высоконагруженного сервера возможно нужен будет свой аллокатор и не нужна будет такая проверка совсем (так как realloc не будет использоваться совсем)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy ох, если в этом ошибка, то недолго и сойти с ума с таких нюансов, ибо я очень невнимателен). 

Насчет проверки на NULL: знаю, что это нужно делать (VS подсказывает постоянно об этом). Решил просто в таком простом примере сделать как меньше кода - для читабельности. Хотя, может, это и ошибка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Не хватает места под нулевой символ в конце строки. (strlen(temp) + sym) -> (strlen(temp) + 1 + sym)

Ответом на мой вопрос был этот маленький нюанс. Нужно не забывать выделять память под '\0'. Спасибо!